# Appium: How do you run Java tests and devices on local machine against a remote appium server

Tags: java, android, appium

Is it possible to have Appium running on a remote machine, while having a device connected to a local machine, and also run the tests from the local machine?

Currently, Appium continues to check adb for devices where Appium is running (which of course there is none) and fails after timing out.  I have zero problems running Appium locally.

Here are my Capabilities running from the Local machine where the device is connected ( IP: 192.168.1.78 ) :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "SCH-I545");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "<appPackage_goes_here>");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "<appActivity_goes_here>");
    driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://192.168.2.109:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

And here is the Appium Console Log from the Remote machine ( IP: 192.168.2.109 ):

```
QA1@QA1s-Mac-mini:3.2: ~/appium :$node .
info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.0 (REV 83e64a139b928fb1f6c06e50370f9f0140ecaa30)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"SCH-I545","browserName":"","appActivity":"com.alldigital.android.cox.NewsActivity","appium-version":"1.2","appPackage":"com.cmgdigital.wsoctvhandset"}}
debug: The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : appium-version
debug: Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
debug: Creating new appium session b184a564-321d-4753-af63-9bd7fbf56b6e
info: Starting android appium
debug: Using fast reset? true
debug: Preparing device for session
debug: Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
debug: Checking whether adb is present
debug: Using adb from /Users/QA1/android-sdk-macosx/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info: Retrieving device
debug: Trying to find a connected android device
debug: Getting connected devices...
debug: executing: "/Users/QA1/android-sdk-macosx/sdk/platform-tools/adb" devices
debug: 0 device(s) connected
debug: Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
debug: executing: "/Users/QA1/android-sdk-macosx/sdk/platform-tools/adb" kill-server
debug: Getting connected devices...
debug: executing: "/Users/QA1/android-sdk-macosx/sdk/platform-tools/adb" devices
debug: 0 device(s) connected
....... continues trying .......
debug: Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
debug: Cleaning up android objects
debug: Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android  device.
debug: Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
    at ADB.getDevicesWithRetry (/Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:612:15)
    at androidCommon.prepareActiveDevice (/Users/QA1/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:354:12)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/QA1/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:294:26)
    at /Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:610:21
    at /Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17
    at iterate (/Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:149:13)
    at /Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:160:25
    at /Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:251:21
    at /Users/QA1/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:615:34
    at androidCommon.prepareEmulator (/Users/QA1/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:344:5)
debug: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)","origValue":"Could not find a connected Android device."},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 30473.764 ms - 206
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but as per my experience Appium server and devices should be on same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.2.109:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your solution

Comment: This did not work. Appium still expects a device connected to same machine where the server is running. Also, changing to RemoteWebDriver required changing the app path and moving the .apk file to where the Appium server was running as well